# Given token id of ERC1155, how to find out how many copies of it are there?

Tags: nft, alchemy, api

This may not be possible to implement in an easy fashion via the standard calls only to blockchain, therefore I'd consider third-party API providers such as Alchemy.com

I'm aware of, let's say, `getNFTs` method, but it doesn't return the amount of copies an ERC1155 token has, does it?

How would one do it then?

P.S.

I've said Alchemy.com! Not aMoralis.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the contract and token ID then you shouldn't need any indexer as long as the contract you're interested in has the ERC1155Supply [extension](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc1155#ERC1155Supply).

Then it will have the `totalSupply(id)` function.

Comment: there's no condition that my contract implements `ERC1155Supply extension.` to begin with

Comment: moreover, my question is about circulating amount of tokens rather than the maximal allowed

Comment: The totalSupply function would give you the circulating amount. But if the contract does not contain that extension I'm not sure what to do. Alchemy does not return that data in its NFT API.